# Same line quantity counter (+/-)

Tags: html, sass

I'm having some trouble trying to implement a quantity counter like so

[image]

Here is what I have so far ([Codepen](http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/qaErby?editors=1100))

My problem is that I keep getting random white space and it feels the way Im going about wrapping the elements is inefficient. Is there any other way to go about making this?

**HTML**

```
<!-- Quantity -->
<div class="quantity-number-v2 clearfix">
  <div class="quantity-wrapper">
    <i class="add-down add-action fa fa-minus"></i>
    <input id="prodQuantity" type="text" name="quantity" value="700" />
    <i class="add-up add-action fa fa-plus"></i>
  </div>
  <div id="stock" class="text-center"></div>
</div>
<!-- /Quantity -->
```

**SCSS**

```
.quantity-number-v2{
  margin: 50px;
  #prodQuantity{
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #222;
  }
  i{
    padding: 6.8px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #222;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space is caused as you are lining up inline elements (think words in a sentence - they have spaces between them). You can comment out the space between your elements to remove the space:

```html
<!-- Quantity -->
<div class="quantity-number-v2 clearfix">
  <div class="quantity-wrapper">
    <i class="add-down add-action fa fa-minus"></i><!--
    --><input id="prodQuantity" type="text" name="quantity" value="700" /><!--
    --><i class="add-up add-action fa fa-plus"></i>
  </div>
  <div id="stock" class="text-center"></div>
</div>
<!-- /Quantity -->
```

[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpYraA?editors=1100)

Comment: Wow that's actually really interesting I notice if you put them all on the same line it works as well +1